# Handling 1/2^n when determining big-O runtime?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I have to find the big-O Notation of the following expression:

> 2n + n(logn)<sup>10</sup> + (1/2)<sup>n</sup>

If I ignore the coefficients, I get 2n + n (log n)<sup>10</sup> plus some term involving 1/2. If I ignore the coefficients, I completely lose the last term, but it doesn't seem right to include them.

How should I handle the (1/2)<sup>n</sup> term?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large `n`, `(1/2)n` approaches 0 and becomes negligible. Also, `2n` eventually becomes negligible compared to `n(logn)10`, since the latter grows faster.

Comparing `n(logn)10` to `2n` is equivalent to comparing `(logn)10` to `2` (since both contain a factor of `n`). Clearly, `(logn)10` will surpass `2` for large enough `n`s -- actually all it takes is an `n` of `3`. As `n` grows further, the difference between these two terms will increase as well and the significance of the `2n` term will become smaller and smaller.

Therefore, the big O expression we're left with is

```
O(n(logn)10)
```

Comment: Thank you and I have two questions for you...

General Question: How do you do the exponents like you did in the answer.

Would that be an appropriate answer to leave it like that?

Comment: @GiBiT09 Are you referring to the (1/2)^n term?

Comment: OO you edited the answer. Thank you for making it more clear. No I didn't know you could keep the exponent `(logn)^10` in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Think about what happens to (1/2)<sup>n</sup> as n gets large.  This term gets smaller and smaller and smaller and eventually becomes completely negligible.  (In fact, if you pick n = 30, it's smaller than 1 / 1,000,000,000.)  One useful observation is that (1/2)<sup>n</sup>) is never greater than 1/2, so you could note that

> 2n + n(log n)<sup>10</sup> + (1/2)<sup>n</sup> ≤ 2n + n(log n)<sup>10</sup> + 1/2

From there, you can see that this is O(n (log n)<sup>10</sup>), since the n (log n)<sup>10</sup> term grows faster than the 2n term.

Normally, though, you have to be careful with exponentials.  Anything of the form a<sup>n</sup> for a > 1 will grow faster than any polynomial, so normally you would drop the polynomials and leave the exponential.  Here, you do the opposite.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok yes this definitely helps.